# Get final Lightning input value in LWC JS

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput

I have a lightning-input tag in my LWC HTML file and i want to get the final value of the text which user inputs. I have a onchange event but it gives me value on every change.
for eg. if the user inputs good. It gives me values as g,go,goo,good.
I want the last value i.e. good.

`<lightning-input type="text" required label="Please provide details" placeholder="Add your comments"  onchange={handleTextChange} name={question.questionApiName} value={textValue}></lightning-input>`

Comment: Just when is it that you actually need the value? During a button execution? If so, you could always find the input in your template DOM when that button is executed, and simply get that input's "value" property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a lookup inputs, generally its recommended to add a [timeout](https://github.com/forcetrekker/lwc-lookup/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/lookup/lookup.js#L83) to avoid any unnecessary Apex calls.

---

If you want to get the final value after the change, use the [onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) event .

> The blur event fires when an element has lost focus.

Here is a [playground link](https://sfse-001-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/FZQN4KBfE/2/edit).